# How to Uninstall IVONA SAPI voice?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, tts

I've installed one of the IVONA 2 voices and the trial period is now expired. I need to uninstall this version completely to buy and install the full version. But I can't seem to get rid of the current installation no matter how I try. It ends up with the following error.

[image]

I've even tried using safemode. Still doesn't allow me to uninstall. I don't wanna use 3rd party uninstallation tools and mess up the registry. Just want to proceed with a clean uninstallation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as a proper solution. But managed to completely uninstall IVONA using '**Revo uninstaller pro**'. It was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete ivona_sapi5_voice_v1.6.60 located in C:\Program Files (x86)\IVONA\IVONA 2 Voice\x86. File name might differ a little.

Comment: Tried. Didn't work. Only thing that worked was Revo uninstaller pro.